# Assign to array that can allow NULL members, without using the heap?

Tags: c++, null

Are there any simple, effective answers to this?... aside from, "Decide which is more important", that is.

Let me elaborate. I want a fixed size array. It represents session slots that can be opened for a socket server to accept clients. There are a limited number of these (four, at present).

Perhaps from a C++ perspective my question is all wrong. Perhaps I should be considering these as session slots which, while filled with session objects, may not necessarily be usable until a given session has a reference to a connected TCP socket.  This differs from most dynamic languages where I could simply specify the session slots as null until such time as a session fills that slot in the array.

Comment: What do you mean by a "NULL object"?  You can have a null pointer...

Comment: What is a null object?  Try a pointer.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to _optionally_ create an object of automatic storage duration?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth & HansPassant: Yes. I know. But how can I have an object which is "unusable" (at least for the time being -- say in an array)?, put it that way. Do I have to give it members that designate it as being "unusable?

Comment: @NickWiggill: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @tenfour, can you write that as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @NickWiggill: Boost::optional is basically the only answer you'll get if there is no "dummy" state for those sockets.  It's a pretty easy option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from still using pointers. Pointers can point to any non-temporary objects, including ones that live on the stack.

Example:

```
void func()
{
    MyObject obj;
    MyObject* p = 0;

    if(some_condition)
        p = &obj;

    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't like this answer.  Can you post demo code showing how one would do this?

Comment: And how do you plan on having those "stack allocated objects" (i.e. *automatic storage* objects) allocated dynamically?

Comment: There is a lot of anger here, today. @R.MartinhoFernandes, can you please explain the limitations of tenfour's suggested approach?

Comment: It's true this answer is not great but it is one nonetheless; personally I upvoted your answer @R.MartinhoFernandes. I will add code.

Comment: Note that this requires `MyObject` to have a dummy state. I apologize if I came across as angry. I am not.

Comment: OK. So I think, then, that when specifying a list of anything that I wish to be stack allocated, I really have no choice but to have dummy objects. That is, unless there is some custom stack allocation taking place, and that seems to be a rarer thing. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes not any more than `boost::optional`, although at least `optional` attempts to wrap some more meaning around this pair of values.

Comment: @tenfour: no, boost::optional does not require that. boost::optional is a container: it *doesn't*  store  the object if it is empty. Doing otherwise would make it completely pointless.

Comment: @NickWiggill most compilers have a stack version of `malloc` (for example `_alloca`). This combined with placement `new` and you can do it. But it's not a *practical* solution unless there is really a problem with using a dummy object. And I doubt that's the case because you're already putting it on the stack, implying that it's a pretty lightweight object.

Comment: Seems I underestimated `boost::optional`. Excuse me.

Comment: @tenfour: I think that's effectively how boost::optional works (though I expect it uses an internal buffer rather than `alloca`.)  Also, my origional problem with your post was I was under the mistaken assumption the goal was to return an optional value from a function.

Answer (score 12):

If you want an object with automatic storage that has optional semantics (i.e. may or may not exist), you can use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

`boost::optional<T>` is a container that can have zero or one elements. If it is empty, it doesn't store a `T` object, just like an empty vector doesn't store any object. In fact, you can think of `boost::optional<T>` as as `std::vector<T>` whose capacity is always 1 and cannot grow. And since the storage size required for this is fixed and known at compile-time (it's `sizeof(T)`), `boost::optional` doesn't need any dynamic allocation.

Comment: +1: I was expecting the first answer to incur my wrath for runaway terminology errors and frustrating grammatical bugs... and then you post this perfect gem!

Comment: I've upvoted because after your explaining more about boost::optional, I think this _would_ be the better solution for most people who ever view this (currently -4 rated) question. I don't use boost, and I barely use std. That is fairly normal for game developers from what I understand. I personally tend not to like what I see when profiling, when I use std.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: @NickWiggill you can change this to the accepted answer; I won't be offended.

Comment: @tenfour No, that's not it at all. This is an excellent answer, but was not the answer I needed. Your indicating that blind spot in my (admittedly rusty) knowledge of C++ made the whole question moot. I still learnt from you all, in the process though. So thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

speculating on [tenfour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8493782/845092), this code would work, and is actually common:

```
bool function(int parameter, TYPE& return_val) {
    if (parameter > 7) {
        return_val = 7;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It's not a pointer, but it's simple.  pass the return by reference, and if you assigned it a value, return true.  Otherwise, return false.

Comment: Isn't it easier to simply say `if (ptr)`? Zero evaluates to `false` automatically, just as non-zero does to `true`.

Comment: This requires objects to have a dummy state.

Comment: Yes, this does require objects to have a dummy state.  @NickWiggill: I still can't figure out how to write a function returning a pointer value like that, where the object is on the stack, without duplicating boost::optional.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I'd rather take the hit of unused objects on the stack, than bring whole other libraries to bear for small problems like these. In my case, with pointers, it would be: `Session* sessions = new Session*[4]; /*do stuff to assign sessions;*/ if (sessions[0]) processClient(sessions[0].client);`, or without: `Session sessions[4]; /*do stuff to assign sessions;*/ if (sessions[0].isValid) processClient(sessions[0]);`

Comment: I should say (as tenfour pointed out) with pointers *on the heap*.